# Can I use histogram visualitation for tensorflow in my python notebook?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tensorflow

I want to use the chart that uses Tensorflow (see image), But in the [example](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/tensorboard_histograms), I chart the histogram on the board of Tensorfow. How can I use the library to plot in my own notebook?

[image]
something like:

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.plothistogram(...)
```

note:
I have already installed Tensorflow library in my notebook

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not, the code for building histograms etc. is part of Tensorboard, not Tensorflow. 
You can write the code yourself using something like [matplotlib.pyplot](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html), but you'd be in for a bit of work.

You would need to obtain the values you're interested in manually during training and store them, then plot them at the end.